# Get a list of variables used, that are not declared within the function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a list of variables that are used yet not declared in a script. I am creating a better code obfuscator, but one thing is that the obfuscated script cannot access outside variables because of the setup of the scope (it is intentional). So I am trying to fix it, by "transfering" the variables that are used outside the script. Lets say I have a function:

```
var somevar = " world"; // this represents non obfuscated "outside" code

(function() { // This represents the obfuscated code
var a = "hello";
console.log(a + somevar);
})();
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
var somevar = " world";
(function(console,somevar) {
var a = "hello";
console.log(a + somevar);
})(console,somevar)
```

But in order to do that, I must get a list of variables that are used, yet not declared within the function. (`console` and `somevar` are the variables not declared, they are not declared in the function, yet they are used)

BTW: This is basically a string manipulation problem

EDIT: Some clarification

I am trying to get the list from a STRING. So using `window` will not work

EDIT: More clarification

Since I am making a obfuscations script, it doesnt run the script to be obfuscated, I just have the unevaluated script as a string.

EDIT: Even more clarification

If I input this into the answer to this:

```
"var a = 'foo';console.log(a + b)"
```

It should output

```
["b","console"]
```

Comment: I'm confused. What in your example are the variables not declared inside the function?

Comment: console and somevar

Comment: @putvande the OP wants to be able to pass those variables declared outside his immediately invoked function automatically, he doesn't want to pass them manually

Comment: In this case they are.. you pass them in as parameters making them local variables.

Comment: @Dummy, Yes, I am trying to do this automatically in my obfuscator script

Comment: "_`console` and `somevar` ... are not declared in the function_" Yes, they are, all variables introduced within the argument list are declared before the function body.

Comment: I would think your best bet would be to use a library like [Acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn) to parse your source.  It can give you information like this: https://astexplorer.net/#/ZNV5DLoTQ5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `with` statement with a proxy:

```js
var somevar = " world"; // this represents non obfuscated "outside" code
var externalVars = [];
with(new Proxy(Object.create(null), {
  has: function(_, identifier) {
    externalVars.push(identifier);
  }
})) (function() { // This represents the obfuscated code
  var a = "hello";
  console.log(a + somevar);
})();
console.log("External vars:", externalVars);
```

If what you have is a string with the code, then you can just use `eval`.

```js
var somevar = " world"; // this represents non obfuscated "outside" code
var externalVars = [];
with(new Proxy(Object.create(null), {
  has: function(_, identifier) {
    externalVars.push(identifier);
    return !(identifier in window);
  }
})) (function() { // This represents the obfuscated code
  eval("var a = 'foo';console.log(a + b)");
})();
console.log("External vars:", externalVars);
```

If you do not want to run the code and only get the identifiers, you can add additional proxy traps in order to only let the code deal with a proxy membrane which prevents side-effects. Note this may be difficult to do properly, and the code may behave differently if there are conditionals or loops.

```js
var somevar = " world"; // this represents non obfuscated "outside" code
var externalVars = [];
var proxy = new Proxy(function(){}, {
  apply: function() {
    return proxy;
  },
  has: function(_, identifier) {
    externalVars.push(identifier);
    return true;
  },
  get: function(_, identifier) {
    if (identifier === Symbol.toPrimitive) return () => null;
    if (identifier === Symbol.unscopables) return undefined;
    return proxy;
  }
  // Add necessary traps
});
with(proxy) (function() { // This represents the obfuscated code
  var a = "hello";
  console.log(a + somevar);
})();
console.log("External vars:", externalVars);
```

Comment: is there a way to do this so it gets it from a unevaluated script? (string) Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Evalutate the string with `eval`.

Comment: It wouldnt work. What if I am running a nodejs script, theres no `require()` on the browser, or `fs`. It would throw an error. Thanks though

Comment: @Andrew Of course if it's node.js code, you need a node.js implementation to run it correctly, and analogous for browser code. But do you want to run the code, or only get the identifiers? If the latter, then you can manage something with proxies.

Answer (score 0):

```
"function(global){"+yourcode+"}.call(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window||global)),JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window||global)));"
```

Yourcode can access global -> local copied variables using this or global

```
this.somevar==somevar;//false
//local.        global.
global.somevar;
//local.
```

My Try to get the vars

```
var jsvars=["var","let","const","function","(",")","{","}","=","==","===",";"];
jsvars.forEach(e=>yourcode=yourcode.replace(e,""));
yourcode=new Set(yourcode.split(" "));
```

Yourcode should now be an array of vars

Comment: So that means no "window"

Comment: The code is read from a string, it is not parsed. This problem is a string manipulation problem

Comment: I clarified further on my question

Comment: @Andrew: why dont you do "(function(window){"+yourcode+"}).call(this,this);"

Comment: It wont work because I am not trying to pass on just `this` but rather other variables as well.

Comment: Other vars will automatically be part of this/window: var somevar==this.somevar==window.somevar you just need to access it using this or window inside of yourcode

Comment: Heres the thing, Obfuscated script from my obfuscator should be able to run on all environments. Window would not work on NodeJs

Comment: Probably not. And to access the variables used by call, I would have to convert every variable into `this.[variablename]`.

Comment: You need to parse the whole js to get the logic. Thats really complex... Thats rather a gihub project then a question on SO

Comment: No, no you dont. You can split the string into keywords, then take the ones that are variables, then check if they are declared.

Comment: @andrew: ive tried sth lile that, have a look. However, that doesnt work perfectly...